# grandchild object does not updated

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have a parent, a child and a grandchild object.
The problem is, when I delete the grandchildren in the application and save
the parent object, grandchildren changes don't be updated.

In Parent Class

```
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent")
  @ForeignKey(name = "FK_1")
  @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
  private Set<Child> children;
```

In Child Class

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent")
  @XmlTransient
  private parent parent;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "child")
  @ForeignKey(name = "FK_2")
  @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
  private Set<GrandChild> grandchildren;
```

In GrandChild Class

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "child", nullable = false)
  @XmlTransient
  private Child child;
```

I use hibernate 4.2.2.Final.

any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by `when I delete the grandchildren in the application`? Post service code which does this.

Comment: I show the list of the grandchildren in the app. The user can select and delete them from the list. There is a SAVE button, by clicking, the updated parent object will be saved. In Debug mode, I checked the parent object, there is no item in the list, but they are remained in the DB.

Comment: Do you set `child` to `null` in every removed grandchild?

Comment: yes, I checked with null and an empty HashSet.

Comment: Are you actually invoking `delete`/`remove` anywhere? Because I don't see `orphanRemoval` in your mapping, and without it nothing is going to be deleted unless you explicitly tell Hibernate to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding orphanRemoval to your collections.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval=true)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "child", orphanRemoval=true)
```

Comment: Thank you. and also I used merge instead of saveOrUpdate. and now it works.

Comment: @Masha can you mark it as correct? Does your code just work with merge without using orphanRemoval?